# django KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"

Tags: python, django

I've created an model Girl
When I open python console and write `from .models import Girl`
I get an error:

```
>>> from .models import Girl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Did you try putting the app name before ".models"?

```
>> from [app_name].models import Girl
```

Comment: Could you please explain how it fixes this problem?

Comment: `.models` tries to import from `models.py` in the current directory, which if using Django shell, is the project directory. But `models.py` is actually located in the app directory.