# Bulkcreate in Django with pandas from django shell

Tags: python, django, csv, model

I'm trying to run a script from the django shell to bulkcreate a database from a csv. I'm not sure if my pandas is wrong or my django model is to blame. I'm using Python3 and I'm not sure if that affects things either. I'm getting pretty lost in the django docs

I want to import this csv from kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/weil41/flights/data

script:

```
    import pandas as pd
from .models import Flight

data = pd.read_csv('data/Flights.csv', sep=',')

# year,month,day,dep_time,dep_delay,arr_time,arr_delay,cancelled,
# carrier,tailnum,flight,origin,dest,air_time,distance,hour,min
flights = [
    Flight(
        year = data.ix[row]['year'],
        month = data.ix[row]['month'],
        day = data.ix[row]['day'],
        dep_time = data.ix[row]['dep_time'],
        dep_delay = data.ix[row]['dep_delay'],
        arr_time = data.ix[row]['arr_time'],
        arr_delay = data.ix[row]['arr_delay'],
        cancelled = data.ix[row]['cancelled'],
        carrier = data.ix[row]['carrier'],
        tailnum = data.ix[row]['tailnum'],
        flight = data.ix[row]['flight'],
        origin = data.ix[row]['origin'],
        dest = data.ix[row]['dest'],
        air_time = data.ix[row]['air_time'],
        distance = data.ix[row]['distance'],
        hour = data.ix[row]['hour'],
        min = data.ix[row]['min'],
    )
    for row in data
]
Flight.objects.bulk_create(flights)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# year,month,day,dep_time,dep_delay,arr_time,arr_delay,cancelled,
# carrier,tailnum,flight,origin,dest,air_time,distance,hour,min

class Flight(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    month = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    day = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    dep_time = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    arr_time = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    arr_delay = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    cancelled = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    carrier = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    tailnum = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    flight = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    dest = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    air_time = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    distance = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    hour = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    min = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.flight} {self.dest} {self.year} {self.month} {self.day}'
```

The error I get is KeyError: "'**name**' not in globals"?

Error message:

> > > exec(open('calendarapp/get_data.py').read())
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "", line 2, in 
> > >       KeyError: "'**name**' not in globals"

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace of the error? I would like to see where the error is originating.

Comment: Hi thanks for your patience - including stack trace in question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894486/django-keyerror-name-not-in-globals) for a similar case.

Based on the solution there, you could try to change the import statement from

```
from .models import Flight
```

to

```
from [app_name].models import Flight
```

In your case it seems this would result in:

```
from calendarapp.models import Flight
```

---

EDIT: I suggest changing you iteration procedure.

```
flights = [
    Flight(
        year = row['year'],
        ...
    )
    for i, row in df.iterrows()]
Flight.objects.bulk_create(flights)
```

Note how I used [pandas `iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), which makes the code a bit more readable.

You could read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation-how-are-they-different) for some context of how to use `.ix` (**or why not to use it**).

Also, [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) does not handle the creation of ID fields yet (if its **not** Postgres).

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but it seems to have solved the problem in the past.

Comment: That does solve something it seems! Now I'm getting 'KeyError: 'year' ?

Comment: @Davtho1983 see my updated anser, maybe that is the cause of the `KeyError`.

Comment: You're right about the typo, I think I'm using a version of pandas where ix is deprecated anyway so that might affect it. I changed syntax to year = data.iloc[row, 0], which gives a ValueError so it's not iterating over it by variable row?

Comment: @Davtho1983 that depends: does your variable `data` have a index with names for the columns or just position? You can find out with `print(data.columns)`.

Comment: Ah no! I get TypeError: 'Index' object is not callable - but when I print(data.head()) it seems to recognise the column names as names of columns? Do I need to specify column names in the read_csv call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170302/discussion-between-ralf-and-davtho1983).